# Why does our Canon PowerShot A1400 keep resetting to "L" resolution?

Tags: canon, resolution, camera-settings, powershot

We have three Canon PowerShot A1400 cameras.  Resolution on all of them has been set to S.  Two of them hold this, but the third one resets itself to L every time we turn the camera off and on again.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to check the settings? Are there any different between the cameras? I mean if there is some kind of reset setting on the power button that have been turned on.

Comment: They are identical cameras.  I can't see anything in the settings to make the camera automatically reset to default when it's turned on.  Do you know where this would be?

Comment: If the rest of your settings aren't valuable, you could try performing a factory reset on all three cameras.